# How would I use an object from another animation in Unity?

Tags: unity, 3d, animation, animator

So I have two different .blend files with two different animations. Let's call my aiming with a gun animation animation A, and my other .blend file with idle, run, and jump animations animation B. If I wanted to play the aiming clip from animation A with the Animation B animator, it just looks like my character wants to shake hands, since the gun doesn't appear in the animation. The aiming animation works if I play animation A with animation A's animator. How would I use the gun object from animation A when playing animation A in animation B's animator?  [Here is an image of what the animation looks like in the import settings (what i want) and in the actual game (what is happening which I don't want.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6xrU.jpg) The top image is what I want and the bottom image is what is happening. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Presumably you tried taking the gun object from character A, and placing it as a child of the corresponding bone in character B?

Comment: Yea, I made it a child of character B, which is an empty object with a child camera, child character mesh, and a child rig. In character A it's the same however, the gun is a child of the empty object, and the rig of character B has two more bones for the gun. @DMGregory

Comment: And you tried parenting the gun to the hand bone in Unity?

Comment: Yup, the gun is parented to the forearm bone in Unity. @DMGregory